# Initialize a vector array of strings

Tags: c++, stl

Would it be possible to initialize a vector array of strings?

for example:

```cpp
static std::vector<std::string> v; //declared as a class member
```

I used `static` just to initialize and fill it with strings. Or should i just fill it in the constructor if it can't be initialized like we do with regular arrays.

Comment: Initialize it with what, exactly?  There are of course a myriad of ways to initialize it.

Comment: `static` doesn't "fill it with strings". The std::vector is a dynamic data structure and is created empty.

Comment: `static` in this context means multiple instances of your class all share the same `v`, is that what you really want?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Sort of:

```
class some_class {
    static std::vector<std::string> v; // declaration
};

const char *vinit[] = {"one", "two", "three"};

std::vector<std::string> some_class::v(vinit, end(vinit)); // definition
```

`end` is just so I don't have to write `vinit+3` and keep it up to date if the length changes later. Define it as:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
T * end(T (&ra)[N]) {
    return ra + N;
}
```

Comment: can i just use int numElements = sizeof(vinit)/4;

Comment: @cpx: if `sizeof(char*)` is 4, yes. Not so much on a 64bit machine. I just got bored of typing a bunch of `sizeof` stuff every time I iterate an array. My `end` function has the same effect for arrays as `std::end` in C++0x does.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, when I say "my" `end` function, I mean the function template in my answer, in contrast with C++0x's `std::end`. I don't claim to have invented it!

Comment: @SteveJessop can you explain how end works? I cant figure it out. It takes N also as an argument but you dont give to it....

Comment: @RoozbehG: `N` is deduced as `3` from the type of the argument `vinit`, which is `const char* [3]`. For that matter, `T` is also deduced as `const char *` from that same type. So writing `end(vinit)` is like writing `end<const char*, 3>(vinit)` thanks to template parameter deduction.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I guess static member `v` should be public instead of private.

Comment: @srini: I don't know, it depends how it's used. Presumably there's some other code in the real version of the class...

Comment: @cpx re: `sizeof(vinit)/4` for this to be cross-architecture you really need to use `sizeof(vinit)/sizeof(vinit[0])` But Steve Jessop's template is prettier to read.

Answer (score 87):

It is 2017, but this thread is top in my search engine, today the following methods are preferred (initializer lists)

```
std::vector<std::string> v = { "xyzzy", "plugh", "abracadabra" };
std::vector<std::string> v({ "xyzzy", "plugh", "abracadabra" });
std::vector<std::string> v{ "xyzzy", "plugh", "abracadabra" };
```

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists

Answer (score 36):

If you are using cpp11 (enable with the `-std=c++0x` flag if needed), then you can simply initialize the vector like this:

```
// static std::vector<std::string> v;
v = {"haha", "hehe"};
```

Answer (score 15):

```
 const char* args[] = {"01", "02", "03", "04"};
 std::vector<std::string> v(args, args + 4);
```

And in C++0x, you can take advantage of `std::initializer_list<>`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Initializer_lists

Answer (score 11):

MSVC 2010 solution, since it doesn't support `std::initializer_list<>` for vectors but it does support `std::end`

```
const char *args[] = {"hello", "world!"};
std::vector<std::string> v(args, std::end(args));
```

Answer (score 5):

same as @Moo-Juice:

```
const char* args[] = {"01", "02", "03", "04"};
std::vector<std::string> v(args, args + sizeof(args)/sizeof(args[0])); //get array size
```

Comment: doesn't this assume all args[] in the init list are the same size?

Comment: @jwillis0720: all args[n] are actually of the same size, sizeof(char*) to be precise. The reason is that args stores a pointer (char*) to the "thing", not the "thing" itself.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`boost::assign`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

In C++0x you will be able to initialize containers just like arrays

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#init-list