# Template variable as string instead of const char *

Tags: c++, string, templates, char

I like vectors, and generally use them over arrays.  For that reason I created a templated variadic function to initialize vectors (included below).

Header (.h):

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> initVector(const int argCount, T first, ...);
```

Source (.hpp):

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> initVector(const int argCount, T first, ...) {
    vector<T> retVec;
    retVec.resize(argCount);

    if(argCount < 1) { ... }

    retVec[0] = first;

    va_list valist;
    va_start(valist, first);
    for(int i = 0; i < argCount-1; i++) { retVec[i+1] = va_arg(valist, T); }
    va_end(valist);

    return retVec;
}
```

It works great for most types (e.g. int, double...), but not for strings---as the compiler interprets them as 'const char *', thus

```
vector<string> strvec = initVector(2, "string one", "string two");
```

gives me the error:

```
error: conversion from ‘std::vector<const char*, std::allocator<const char*> >’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >’ requested
```

Is there any way to get the string arguments to be interpreted as strings without having to cast each one?

Comment: It wouldn't be a pretty solution, but maybe I could pass 'string' as an additional argument which would then automatically cast to each element?   :/

Comment: Is it too burdensome to tell the compiler which type you want rather than relying on deduction? `initVector<std::string>(2,"string 1","string 2")` for example.

Comment: In addition to your immediate problems, it's illegal to pass non-POD types as varargs.

Comment: @ahenderson: I believe the error message is not caused by that line, but by the fact that template argument deduction is trying to fit the type parameter `T` to 2 different types *at the point where the function is called*.

Comment: @bames53: You're correct, but that's only a problem for solutions that try to do the conversion to `string` before the arguments are passed to the function.  If raw `const char*`s are passed (as in my suggested solution), we're still good.

Comment: @tmpearce this solution fails because varargs can't accept non-POD types --- as barnes53 points out.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do... if the first argument is the size, why do you want to explicitly mention the second argument? If you want it for type deduction, it will not work as literals are not `std::string`

Comment: @dribeas sorry, I don't follow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the type of the constant `"string one"` is `const char*` and not `std::string` there needs to be a conversion. `va_arg` can not make this conversion, so we need a second template argument:

```
template <typename VecT, typename EleT>
std::vector<VecT> init_vector(const size_t nargs, EleT first, ...) {
    std::vector<VecT> result;
    result.reserve(nargs);

    if (nargs == 0) {
        return result;
    }

    result.push_back(first);

    if (nargs == 1) {
        return result;
    }

    va_list valist;
    va_start(valist, first);

    for (int i = 1; i < nargs; ++i) {
        result.push_back(VecT(va_arg(valist, EleT)));
    }

    va_end(valist);

    return result;
}

std::vector<std::string> = init_vector<std::string>(2, "string one", "string two")
```

Note that I made some changes, most notably change `resize` to `reserve`, to prevent unnecessary objects from being created.

---

You can also simply use this (no risk of having number of elements messed up, and type safe):

```
const char *args[] = {"string one" , "string two"};
std::vector<std::string> strvec(args, args + sizeof(args)/sizeof(args[0]))
```

---

Or use C++11 initializer lists:

```
std::vector<std::string> strvec = {"string one" , "string two"};
```

---

For fun I made this little thing that is even neater and safer, but doesn't generalize into an arbitrary amount of arguments. It works by overloading. Here are the first three overloads and example usage:

```
template<class C>
inline C init_container() {
    return C();
}

template<class C, class T>
inline C init_container(T arg0) {
    const T args[1] = {arg0};
    return C(args, args + 1);
}

template<class C, class T>
inline C init_container(T arg0, T arg1) {
    const T args[2] = {arg0, arg1};
    return C(args, args + 2);
}

std::vector<std::string> vec =
    init_container< std::vector<std::string> >("hello", "world");
```

A full header (for up to 100 arguments) can be downloaded here: https://gist.github.com/3419369 .

Comment: Awesome answer @nightcracker; that worked like a charm.  A couple of questions:  1) I didn't know about this C++11 initializer lists thing that you and j_random_hacker pointed out---do I need a compiler option to get that to work (it didn't as is).  2) I've always opted out of the 'sizeof(args)/sizeof(args[0])' approach because someone told me it  was 'bad practice' to do so... not to mention its a little unaesthetic.  Is that standard practice, none-the-less?

Comment: @zhermes: still working on a better answer. You can use the array answer perfectly fine, though, even better with the `end` function in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4268956/565635 . What compiler do you use? Then I can give you the flag.

Comment: Technically, the argument "string one" is not a `const char*`, but a `const char [11]` (If I counted correctly), and this answer is overcomplicating the problem... If you are going to pass the type as a template argument, there is no need to create a second type and have it deduced, as the compiler is able to *convert* from one to the other.

Comment: @nightcracker i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (I think that's the correct answer to your question.... <noob>)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: true, but when used in templates `const char[11]` gets converted to `const char*` - I didn' t bother with the technicalities :)

Comment: @dribeas, I don't think that's quite right --- as barnes53 points out in the comments to the initial question, that fails because a string (non-POD) can't be passed to varargs

Comment: @nightcracker, 'cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x" '

Comment: @zhermes: What I suggest is `template <typename T> std::vector<T> initVector( int count, ... )` that will be used as `initVector<std::string>( 2, "a", "b" );`. Note that the argument is **not** a `std::string`, but a *string literal* that is an *array of characters* which will decay to a pointer. I feel you are over complicating the problem (which has a much simpler solution, either use C++11, or `boost::assign`)

Comment: Half of the reason for problem isn't the solution, but the experience of solving it---which is one of numerous reasons I avoid boost whenever possible.  And nightcracker already suggested C++11 and was trying to help me get that working

Comment: It looks like it Need a never version of g++ (gcc), thanks for all the help.

Comment: @dribeas: Your solution using `template <typename T> std::vector<T> initVector( int count, ... )` will give UB (it will compile but fail at runtime) when the types of the 2nd and remaining arguments are convertible to `T` but have a different size (such as when one is `string` and one is `const char*`), because `va_arg` will "step" the wrong amount through the stack.  On C++03, using 2 template parameters is best: if no implicit conversion exists, the compiler will complain.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: yes, I realized that, which is why I updated my answer. Also see my latest edit (the solution on the bottom) which is entirely type-safe and easier to use than the other solutions, but requires an header.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 2 template type parameters instead:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
vector<T> initVector(const int argCount, U first, ...) {
```

Very often (e.g. for `int`, `double` etc.) `T` and `U` will be the same.  But the difference with the new strategy is that we now allow them to be different, provided that there is an implicit conversion from `U` to `T` (such as from `const char*` to `string`).  This should be safe in the sense that, if no implicit conversion exists, you will get a compile-time error.

BTW interesting strategy -- it never occurred to me that `va_list` etc. could be employed in this way!  OTOH, I believe there is new machinery in C++11 that allows vectors etc. to be directly initialised from initialiser lists, similar to how you have always been able to initialise arrays in C like `int a[] = { 3, 4, 5 };`, so it may be better to go with that.

Comment: You don't even need to assign from an initializer_list.  You can use the new initialization syntax to just write `int a[]{ 3, 4, 5 };`