# Adding text at the beginning and at the end of each line

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm somewhat new to programming and I'm making a filter when people search something. I'm coding with Code::Blocks.
For the example, I take some pokemons :

```
Ivysaur
Venusaur
Charmander
Charmeleon
Charizard
Squirtle
Wartortle
Blastoise
Caterpie
Metapod
```

I want to add each of these pokemons to my variable "vector string pokeList" for instance.

```
vector<string> pokeList;
pokeList.push_back("Bulbasaur");
Ivysaur
Venusaur
Charmander
Charmeleon
Charizard
Squirtle
Wartortle
Blastoise
Caterpie
Metapod
```

How do I add "pokeList.push_back("");" to each line without doing it "manually", because adding 700 pokemons "manually" is really long...
PS : I don't want to create a .txt file with the list inside.

Thnaks.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"?

Comment: You don't have them in a text file? Do you have them already in a source file? You must have them stored *somewhere* already, don't you?

Comment: mmm. In Vi: `:%norm IpokeList.push_back("<End>");`

Comment: This sounds like "how do I search/replace text in my IDE?" question, not something to do with C++ specifically. It looks like CodeBlocks supports Regular Expressions in search/replace, so use that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think he has them in a post on [SO] AFAICT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Code::Blocks is using a modern enough compiler, you can solve this without IDE tricks by using a newer feature in the language. In C++11, your example can be written as:

```
auto pokeList = vector<string>{
    "Bulbasaur",
    "Ivysaur",
    "Venusaur",
    "Charmander",
    "Charmeleon",
    "Charizard",
    "Squirtle",
    "Wartortle",
    "Blastoise",
    "Caterpie",
    "Metapod"
};
```

http://ideone.com/b45OeD

Answer (score 2):

Where do you get the pokemon list from? If you have a file with all the names you can just read the file:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> pokeList;

    std::ifstream pokeFile("your file path/name here");
    if (pokeFile.is_open())
    {
        std::string str;
        while (std::getline(pokeFile, str))
        {
            pokeList.push_back(str);
        }

    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";
    }

}
```

now you can edit the list from outside.

p.s it's advised not to put huge static lists like that inside your code, much easier to have it in a separate file.

Comment: Especially considering as it's kind of a waste of time to "build" the list by filling it with names one at a time. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268886/initialize-a-vector-array-of-strings for a better way (but your reading from an external file is way more versatile).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static array with pointers to these string literals and use it to initialize the vector. For example

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

const char * pokemons[] = 
{ 
   "Ivysaur",
   "Venusaur",
   /* other pokemons */ 

   "Metapod"
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> pokeList( std::begin( pokemons ), std::end( pokemons ) );
}
```

You can place the array definition in a separate header file.