# Error when initializing a vector array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, char

I am trying to initialize a vector of strings by first initializing it in an array of char* and convert them into a vector. However the following code doesn't work, the vector ended up having three of the same first string and the forth, fifth, and sixth string.

```
string hand_lr_ = "left";
const char* x_joint_names_char[] = {("r2/"+hand_lr_+"_arm/wrist/yaw").c_str(),("r2/"+hand_lr_+"_arm/wrist/pitch").c_str(),("r2/"+hand_lr_+"_arm/hand/index/distal").c_str(),("r2/"+hand_lr_+"_arm/hand/ringlittle/ringMedial").c_str(),("r2/"+hand_lr_+"_arm/hand/ringlittle/ringDistal").c_str(),("r2/"+hand_lr_+"_arm/hand/ringlittle/ring").c_str() };

std::vector<std::string> x_joint_names(x_joint_names_char, x_joint_names_char + sizeof(x_joint_names_char)/sizeof(x_joint_names_char[0]));

for (int i =0; i < sizeof(x_joint_names_char)/sizeof(x_joint_names_char[0]) ;i++) {
  cout << x_joint_names[i] << endl;
  for (int j = 0; j < strlen(x_joint_names_char[i]); j++)
  {
    cout << x_joint_names_char[i][j];
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

The code above outputs the following. Where a weird character appears.

```
r2/left_arm/wrist/yaw
8�{
r2/left_arm/wrist/yaw
r2/left_arm/wrist/yaw
r2/left_arm/wrist/yaw
r2/left_arm/wrist/yaw
r2/left_arm/hand/ringlittle/ringMedial
r2/left_arm/hand/ringlittle/ringMedial
r2/left_arm/hand/ringlittle/ringDistal
r2/left_arm/hand/ringlittle/ringDistal
r2/left_arm/hand/ringlittle/ring
r2/left_arm/hand/ringlittle/ring
```

The code works correctly if there are only five strings. It also appears normal if I don't assign the array to a vector. All the contents in x_joint_names_char are correct before assigning to a vector. Any idea what is the cause?

The initialization code is based on this post: [Initialize a vector array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268886/initialize-a-vector-array-of-strings)

Edit:
    Moving the hand_lr into the string like the following also works.

```
const char* x_joint_names_char[] = {("r2/left_arm/wrist/yaw"),("r2/left_arm/wrist/pitch"),("r2/left_arm/hand/index/distal"),("r2/left_arm/hand/ringlittle/ringMedial"),("r2/left_arm/hand/ringlittle/ringDistal"),("r2/left_arm/hand/ringlittle/ring") };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  line initializing `x_joint_names_char` creates a pile of dangling pointers.

The expression `("r2/"+hand_lr_+"_arm/wrist/yaw")` denotes a temporary string (since it has no name and wasn't dynamically allocated).  The `c_str()` function produces a pointer to the temporary string, but then the temporary strings on that line are all destroyed when that line completes.

The use of `char *` in the linked thread is a micro-optimization that can only be used when the initializers are C-style string literals.

Since C++11 you can write:

```
std::vector<std::string> x_joint_names = {
    "r2/"+hand_lr_+"_arm/wrist/yaw",
    "r2/"+hand_lr_+"_arm/wrist/pitch",
    "r2/"+hand_lr_+"_arm/hand/index/distal"
};
```

for example. If you are forced to use an old compiler then make your preliminary array be an array of `string`, not an array of `const char *`. Or `push_back` each string into the vector and do away with the array.